# Как заполнить матрицу?

Tags: c++

Здравствуйте. Не могу сообразить, как заполнить матрицу следующим образом:

[image]

Матрица размера 3хN*N, где элементы первой строки меняются с шагом дельта х от -N/2 до N/2 и так N раз. При этом элементы второй строки остаются неизменными в пределах одного "цикла" первой строки. Заранее всем спасибо за помощь.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

бегаешь все время по цикла i, j и по условиях i<1, i=2 или как-то еще выставляешь правила формирования значения

```
for i=0; i<N-1; i++
 for j=0; j<N-1; j++
       if i=1
              //      element[i][j]  ставишь условия
       if i=2
             //      element[i][j]  не изменяешь
```

Comment: Не могу представить изменение значений в цикле подобным образом

Comment: так а если N тысяча?это дофига уловий

Comment: ...где элементы первой строки меняются с шагом...
ты имеешь ввиду матрицу (1k х 1k)значений, в которой каждая строка будет заполнятся по своим правилам? честно, я даже сходу не могу пример, даже самый фантастический, представить

Comment: строки всего три, а колонок может быть много..

Comment: float dN;// шаг по N
        float dY;// шаг по Y
        float kj=0; // начальный номер "блочков" в массиве
        float NN=N/dN;// количество точек по N
        float YY=Y/dY;// количество точек по Y
while (kj<YY) {int kjNN=kj*NN;
        for (int j=0;j<NN;j++)
        {
                Rtarget[0][j+kjNN]=(-N/2+dN*j)*0.01;
                Rtarget[1][j+kjNN]=(-Y/2+dY*kj)*0.01;
                Rtarget[2][j+kjNN]=(Z)*0.01;
                //Memo1->Lines->Add(Rtarget[1][j+kjNN]);
        }kj++;
        }
Вот сделал, может кому пригодится)

Answer (score 1):

На мой взгляд наиболее универсальным способом конструкции для этих целей является передавание лямбды в конструктор.

Может, эта реализация и содержит множество ошибок, это набросок того, о чем я говорю:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <functional>

typedef float val_t;

class A {
    size_t  width_, height_, depth_;
    std::function <void(A &self)> construction_lambda_;
    std::vector <std::vector <std::vector <val_t> > > matrix_;
public:
    A(size_t width, size_t height, size_t depth, std::function <void(A &self)> construction_lambda):
        width_(width),
        height_(height),
        depth_(depth),
        construction_lambda_(construction_lambda),
        matrix_(
            std::vector <std::vector <std::vector <val_t> > >(
                std::vector <std::vector <val_t> >(
                    std::vector <val_t> (
                        0., depth_
                    ), height_
                ), width_
            )
        ),
    {
        for(size_t i = 0; i < depth; ++i)
            for(size_t j = 0; j < width; ++j)
                for(size_t k = 0; k < width; ++k)
                    matrix_[i][j][k] = construction_lambda(i, j, k);
    }
};

const size_t N = 10;
A *instance(N, 3, N, [](size_t width, size_t height, size_t depth) {
        return ...;
    };
);
```

Как видно, теперь можно создавать все просто и элегантно.